AWS EC2 Image Builder Lifecycle Policy - when does it run?
Is there any information available on when a "Lifecycle Policy" is run within AWS EC2 Image Builder?
I created a lifecycle policy for my recipies and started a lot of Image builds.
Nothing is hapenning in the lifecycle policy, no aciton log.
Should it be run after images builds? Does it run on a schedule?
